# Eclipse overwrites my web.xml every time I start the environment

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am running Eclipse Juno with Tomcat 7 on Windows 7 platform.

When I build my project with Maven the web.xml is correctly derived. I go into in eclipse and refresh and check my target\web.xml and so far so good. I run the Tomcat server and everything is as normal.

As soon as I restart Eclipse the web.xml is back to the placeholder version and I have to build from Maven again and refresh the sources before running Tomcat.

I have exactly the same set up on Ubuntu and this doesn't happen.

Under Project Facets I am using Dynamic Web Module 3.0.

=======

```
<artifactId>nordicedge</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>kivadmin2_logic</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>kivUpdater</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
      <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>rome</groupId>
      <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.nordicedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>neim</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.nordicedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>neutil</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>     
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <webXml>${project.build.directory}/web.xml</webXml>
            <warSourceExcludes>**/DSEditor.properties,**/META-INF/context.xml</warSourceExcludes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>web.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/NEIDMgmt</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>DSEditor.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/nordicedge/WEB-INF/NEIDMgmt</targetPath>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>context.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/nordicedge/META-INF</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </resources>    
  </build>
```

Comment: Are you using the `m2eclipse` plugin to manage dependencies in your Maven projects in Eclipse? If so, please make sure that you're running the same version in both of your Eclipse installations.

Comment: yes I am using the same verions. 1.3.1. It still overwrites the web.xml.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml file, or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: The Eclipse Maven Console should list that Maven is running as part of your Eclipse build, it should show you what's going on, maybe that will shed some light on where the issue is.

Comment: I think there is some known problem with filtering web resources - it's preferred you have all filtered resources in normal resources (that makes filtering web.xml impossible)

Comment: Here are the relevant bits of the pom.xml. I also have a problem if I make changes to the source code that it is not republished and the webserver restarted automatically (this works in the Ubuntu setup ok).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **m2e-wtp**, first of all check you're in the latest version, means 0.17. After that, for resource filterings make use of [Maven War plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) in order to filter them in standard build phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xhtml</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```